# LNK2019のリンクエラー

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10

大変申し訳ありませんが、同じようなエラーがまた出てきました。
次のエラーです。

「エラー    LNK2019 未解決の外部シンボル __flsbuf が関数 "void __cdecl ******** で参照されました。」

ちなみに、「legacy_stdio_definitions.lib」はリンクしています。
今度は何が悪かったのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の中に情報が見つかりました。削除された非公開関数だったようです。

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/ja-JP/382bb45c-c911-4704-846a-5573f631ecda/microsoft-visual-studio?forum=vcgeneralja

実装例も散見されますが、どこまで信用できるかわかりません。
とりあえず、空の関数を実装してリンクエラーを解消し、実働状態をみるしかないかもしれません。